# How to enable ts-check in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

Recently I have found Visual Code has a nice feature for type checking in JavaScript files. All I have to do is to type on top of file 
`// @ts-check`, it is great benefit for me, so I want to use it globally on every JavaScript file, how could I could I do it without writing that line every time on top of a file?

Comment: I believe that errors come from typescript compiler and not from eslint. To enable type checking in all js files add _tsconfig.json_ file (if you don't have one) with `checkJs` compiler option enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Aleksey L. comment I added to root directory `tsconfig.json` with this configuration and it works:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "checkJs": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

also if you want to check it with `npm script` all you need is to install `typescript` and use this command in `scripts` section:

`"typecheck": "tsc --project tsconfig.json --noEmit"`