# How to //@ts-check globally on my react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using create-react-app to test a monorepo that i'm creating. Inside the monorepo I have some `index.d.ts` files to declare my packages however I do not wish to start using `.ts` files and would prefer to stick to `.js` files.

I am using the create-react-app as a means to test my packages before publishing them as well as ensuring that the Typescript declaration files are working correctly.

Within my create-react-app I am forced to use `//@ts-check` at the top of the `App.js` file before Typescript starts to check my work.

[image: create-react-app typescript check[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwOVs.png)

I would like the ability to enable a `//@ts-check` globally for my create-react-app's as I plan on using it on all my future and passed projects and adding the `//@ts-check` at top of every `.js` file sounds extremely tedious.

I have tried using a `tsconfig.json` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157373/how-to-enable-ts-check-in-es6) however it did not work.

This picture below is showing the same `App.js` file without the `//@ts-check` and with `tsconfig.json` and as you can see it is no longer checking my file.

[image: create-react-app without typescript check]

I'm fairly new to Typescript so could somebody please explain to me how I could enable `//@ts-check` globally on my create-react-app projects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want the benefits of typescript, Is there any reason for sticking to `.js`?

Comment: @ArchitGarg, Yes, I'm only after the benefits of typescript checking my own packages that I npm install. I don't need to typescript the whole create-react-app. From what I understand, using //@ts-check allows me to check against my typescript declaration files for my packages while continuing to code in vanilla JS which is much easier for me when writing apps.

Comment: So in that case, My suggestion would be to leave `.ts ` files as it is, so that you can take benefit of ts magic. But you can loose typescript rules via "tsconfig.json" so the ts files looks and behaves exactly like es6. Honestly there is no diff b/w ts and js es6

Comment: @ArchitGarg I shall look into it. After further assessment I think I might migrate to TS all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a file at the root of your project with the filename:

`jsconfig.json`

Add the following to the contents of that file:

```js
{
  compilerOptions: {
     "checkJs": true,
     "jsx: "react"
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: This is not a valid json (all keys must be wrapped with double quotes)